# Rigging an already weighted model

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have a model that is already weighted but it doesn’t have any bones.
Is there any way or add-on or something to generate a rig/armature based on the weight and vertex groups?
I know that you have to have a bone for each vertex group (with the same name) and after that you should parent your model using "armature deform" to your rig.
Because you know, There are a lot of vertex groups and if I want to create a rig/armature manually it takes for ever! I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything.
Thanks